# Android permission READ_MEDIA_AUDIO and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for API level < 33

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

In API 33 (Android 13), [granular media permissions have been introduced](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions), and developers have to request these granular permissions instead of `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

`READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` is one such granular permission. This permission exists only in API level 33+, so my question is, **which permission should I request in the *manifest*?**

Since my app has `minSDK = 21`, should I request both `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` in the manifest. Or should I only request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and that will cover `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`? (At runtime, of course, I will ask for either of the permission based on the `SDK_INT` of the device.)

Comment: You put all in manifest. And at runtime you request only permissions as far as used device supports. Well my three cents answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add both permissions to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO"/>
```

The `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO` permission will work only for devices with Android 13 or above.

Then, as you wrote, you should handle each case of the SDK (this section may be helpful for other developers):

- for the SDK 21 and 22 the permission will be added automatically after the app installation
- starting from the SDK 23 you should use the runtime permissions for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission (https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)
- there were changes related to the external storage starting from Android 11 (SDK 30), however, you still can download audio files using the same `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. Regarding the changes, for example the directory `Recordings` exists only from the SDK 31 (source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media_store)
- starting from the SDK 33 request the granulated permission `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's been suggested, if you're just learning and don't know how to request permissions and don't want to mess with it yet, then just do the following:

1. Add these lines to AndroidManifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
```

2. Go to **Settings** → **Apps** → choose your installed app → **Permissions** → and toggle *Storage* on.

P. S. This has worked for me.

Comment: How can we request music and audio permission from our app users?